# VM that works with Java & android

Tags: java, android, scripting-language, vm-implementation

I'm looking to embed some kind of scripting language so that I can use it to handle my map's scripts. I don't want to compile stuff during application's execution - only run the precompiled bytecode. I saw things like luaj, but I'm looking for something as minimalistic as possible. I don't really need the full support of LUA standard libraries, for instance. All I need is basic numeric & string operations + being able to bind my own functions.

I couldn't really find any small-ish VM written in java ( I would want to avoid mixing android's NDK with SDK. My whole game is written in java already ), so if I am forced to - I might just implement some very minimalistic & not fully implemented LUA VM.. (I need procedural programming style only after all. Having only functions without objects etc. would do completely fine)

( Just to clear things out - The VM doesn't need to be LUA VM. It can be any language )

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand; why do you need a VM? Have you explored simple ELs?

Comment: What do you mean by shortcut "EL"? I cannot seem to connect it to anything I know. If you mean something like "Emulated Language", and by that you somehow understand a simple language interpreter, then I don't think that I can get away with such performance.

Comment: Expression Language, like MVEL, OGNL, etc. Or a simple templating, some of which offer expressions.

Comment: Oh! This is very interesting! It might be just what I am looking for :)